# How to track free trial in programming?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, algorithm

I have an application that users can use it 14 days without paying. However, after 14 days users will not be able to use the application unless s/he pays for it.

I don't know how to track the remaining time for the free trial. I'm thinking of setting an cronjob 14 days later when the users is created but I think it is a bit hard to manage (?).

The second thought would be checking the remaining time for every user at a specific time every day but timezone and server loading might be problem in this case.

I'm using MongoDB and Node.js for back-end and HTML, CSS, JS for front-end. How can I design my database and code to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**I believe this question have enough detail please warn before closing.**

Comment: This question was closed because it does not support being answered with a clear, brief code example.  Clearly, you need to have a field with the Date the trail started, and then run code conditional on that date being a certain time period or more in the past.

Comment: I'm not asking for code, please read it. I'm asking for database and code design. You are just offending people that ask question. There is no code that I can publish because I haven't wrote any yet that's why I need for help.

Answer (score 1):

You could possible save time of register of user and then every time on request of users that don't pays calculate the remaining time?

Comment: It makes sense, thank you for your thought. I really want to ensure if it is a good practice. And I don't know why this question is closed.

Comment: And I believe sending an email when the free trial is end would be great. Your solution doesn't cover this.

Comment: Sorry i don't know either

Comment: For that i would need to make so service that will check every hour or day if user's free trial expires that day or hour and that sound too complicated.

Comment: I'm appreciated. My thread is closed for no reason, if you believe there is a Reopen button that you may support to reopen.